Linker "undefined reference" to shared library functions
I'm having a problem with compiling a C project(proj) to use my shared library. The library provides logging and stats-gathering functionalities which I want to freely include in different projects. It's written C which I've been able to successfully use in one of my C++ projects which uses automake as a build system.
The library consists of 3 files, it's built using meson with flags:
-Wall -Winvalid-pch -g -fPIC -MD -MQ 
and linked with:
Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -fPIC -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-soname,libcounters.so
The important files of the library would be:
statistics.h:
const char* print_perf_measurements(measurement_t *measurement, int logger);
extern perf_measurement_t *measure_cycle_count;

statistics.c:
perf_measurement_t *measure_cycle_count;

const char* print_perf_measurements(measurement_t *measurement, int logger)
{
\\body
}

When I try to use the library in proj which consists of 3 .cc files, it seems that the functions from .text are not visible whereas symbols like global variables are found.
At the linking phase:
g++ -W -Wall -g -O2   -o proj file1.o file2.o file3.o  -lpthread -lcap -lcounters -lrt
This error appears:
proj/proj.cc:621: undefined reference to 'print_perf_measurements(measurement_t*, int)'
When checking the symbols, the function and variable are both visible:
nm  -D  /usr/lib/libcounters.so
0000000000002d9c T print_perf_measurements
00000000000141c0 B measure_cycle_count

If I try to link without -lcounters, as expected, I get the same errors with the addition of variables not being visible:
/usr/bin/ld: /proj/file1.cc:621: undefined reference to `measure_cycle_count'
/usr/bin/ld: /proj/file1.cc:621: undefined reference to `print_perf_measurements(measurement_t*, int)'

Since the symbols are visible and I've been able to use this library in another project I suspect the problem might be in the compilation and linking of the proj but I don't have any idea what further to look at.
I've tried adding -fpic and visibility default attributes to the function and reordering the libraries but none of those helped.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards,
Michał

C names are not mangled, C++ names are mangled. You have to use extern "C" in header file when included from C++.

@Yksisarvinen technically they are mangled, not in away to provide polymorphism, but in a way to  show they are global visible functions with certain call conventions. e.g. void _cdecl foo() would be _foo, but in some other cases it can be @foo  or @foo@<insert number here>. _foo is the reason why having underscore name in global namespace is a UB in C++.

Thanks for answers, @Yksisarvinen it's true that when I imported this library into the C++ project I had to use extern "C" but the project that I'm mentioning is just C compiled with gcc. I will edit the question to better reflect that

#ifdef __cplusplus / #error bad compiler / #endif add these to your C source files

@pmg thanks for spotting this silly mistake. I didn't notice that I'm using the C++ compiler. I remember during the course of developing I tried the extern "C" solution but back then I got some other unrelated error which made me mistakenly assume that it's not the problem. With extern the problem is fixed, and it's duplicate of what @Yksisarvinen linked
